# Передача переменной из JS в PHP без обновления страницы

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Как передать переменную из JavaScript в PHP без обновления страницы, внутри существующей функции JS?
Т.е. необходимо сделать PHP запрос к MYSQL базе данных (update), внутри функции JS, без обновления страницы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте про AJAX, он создан именно для таких вещей и намного проще, чем может вначале показаться.
Пример:

AJAX запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : {'distance':'distance'},
    success: function (responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
}});
```

PHP файл:

```
echo $_POST['distance'];
```

Comment: как раз его я и изучаю, его и использую, просто PHP я уже довольно не плохо знаю, а вот на счет JS и AJAX я не особо в теме. столкнулся с этой проблемой в процессе изучения как раз таки

Comment: для примера: создаете файл с php кодом, в js коде делаете ajax запрос к этому файлу, который будет ждать ответа от php файла. С ajax передаете переменные через data а в php получаете их через get или post

Comment: В data название переменной в ковычках надо (не знаю как у вас, но у меня так не работает) ну и значение, если это текст, типо так: `data: {'data':'data'},`

Comment: Правильно, не обратил внимания.